# How to limit keyof T to just string keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extend existing interface:

```
type ColDef = { field: string; }
```

so that I will limit field values only to actual properties of specified type:

```
interface TypeSafeColDef<T> extends ColDef {
   field: keyof T
}
```

but I'm getting:

> Interface 'TypeSafeColDef' incorrectly extends interface
>   'ColDef'.   Types of property 'field' are incompatible.
>       Type 'keyof TRow | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>         Type 'keyof TRow' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>           Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>             Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>               Type 'keyof TRow' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>                 Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>                   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

I've tried following constraint, but no success

```
type StringKey = { [key: string]: any }

interface TypeSageColDef<TRow extends StringKey>
```

Comment: `extends { [key: string]: any }` behaves same as `extends object` for some reason (not limiting keys to be `string` only). Real question is why do you need `extends ColDef`? Do you have more properties in real example?

Comment: I need to extend ColDef because I want to get compiler error when invalid field is passed. I do not own ColDef, it is a 3rd party type definition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your last one comes quite close, we still need to extend `ColDef` and extract a `string` key type for `field`:

```
type ColDef = { field: string; }

interface TypeSafeColDef<T extends object> extends ColDef {
  field: Extract<keyof T, string>
}

// test
type T1 = TypeSafeColDef<{ a: string }> // { field: "a"; }
```

`field` now has type `Extract<keyof T, string>`, because `keyof` supports `string | number | symbol` property names [since TS 2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html). There is a [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `--keyofStringsOnly` to disable this new behavior, if you don't want that.

A second alternative is to define a type alias to get rid of `Extract`. This works due to the nature of the intersection operator [never provoking errors](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24970#issuecomment-397435307):

```
type TypeSafeColDefAlias<T extends object> = ColDef & {
  field: keyof T
}
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwCIQGZQLxQN5VQSwgQBMAuKAZ2ACd8A7AcwG4oBfAKHfuAmtQEMAxtAAq4CAGV+qCPGRoAPCKgQAHjzrEKUOACMAVhEHAAfCvURN2uSnTZ2UPIRLkAouupDgCgNYQQcOgiADSUNPQMJuwc7AD0sVA8VOygkFAiAIyY6eJSMjaKuPzkVLSMbGbxOE5EZFAARPz1LDGpornSsoi2AIII+PwUSuYaWjoGRqbZBegAZDgONS5QfgFB0ZxVScAp4ukATNlikHld8qh9A0NFJeHlrJUJM1DzuAS15I3NbEA)

Comment: `extends StringKey` looks redundant if you're anyway doing `Extract<keyof T, string>`

Comment: yeah, StringKey is not needed in this case. I suggest to edit the answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Liero updated answer (and gave another possible alternative)

Comment: I needed to enforce string type for grid column helper. Here is how I did it `export class GridColumnHelper<T> { ... createColumn(field: Extract<keyof T, string> ... }`. This is instead of `field: keyof T`. Hope it helps someone.